# Upgraded to 13.04, cannot boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, 13.04

I just got through an upgrade to 13.04 and my machine won't reboot. After getting through the boot loader screen, I just get a completely blank display.

What can I do to boot with a console instead of having it try X11? All the answers I've found seem to have been left behind by significant advances in the complexity of the boot parameter menu.

My system is an HP laptop with a secure LVM partition. I've been through about 5 or 6 release upgrades on this same machine, always without incident.

*edit* — I've gotten to a console boot, but regardless of what kernel I try the system hangs at the "Loading `<linux version>`" line.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> still gets you into a non-graphical environment.

Comment: No, it doesn't, sadly.  The boot hangs at the "Loading" line, and that's that.